# HTML5 request response webservice

Tags: javascript, html, request, response, loading

I am pretty new to html5 web development

I have created a page with login and password on it and have a submit button.
On submit , I send a rest request to the server which has a url

THE RRQUEST IS SOMETHING LIKE THIS

```
<USERNAME>
abc
</USERNAME>
<PASSWORD>loooik
</PASSWORD>
```

which is in js file as var data...

This request is set as

```
var parameters=JSON.stringify(data);
```

I use the following code for establishing connection

```
xmlHttp.open("post",url,true);
XmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json);
xmlHttp.send(parameters);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function X()
{
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
{
alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
}
return true;
}
```

I need to add a loading element and want to display the next screen between request and the response. How can I achieve it?

In tag I have used submit input type where onClick attribute calls return sendPost() method which has the request to be called

How should I proceed for the same... having loading screen and getting the response ... suppose just the name to be displayed on next html screen

Comment: try Using jquery, it let you do things very easily

Comment: I am pretty new to html5 development ... please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all see basic jQuery example. This will guide you through how jQuery works and help a lot in the solution I'm going to suggest.

http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

jQuery has it's own AJAX method and further shorthand called [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Now you can write something like this -

```
function requestNetwork() {
    // Code for loading screen
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourURL",
        data: "yourData"
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        // Code for dismissing loading screen
    }).fail(function(data) {
        // Code when call fails
    }).always(function() {
        // This code will always run
    });
}
```

Comment: And if the call fails ?

Comment: is ajax important ... won't my code work ??? 

When I hit the submit button i get a response ... How will i pass the response got to next html page ??

Comment: after done code, you can add two more functions - fail(function(data){ your code }), and always(function() { your code }).
Fail will run if call fails, finally will always run, irrespective of success or failure

Comment: @Yatin the code you've written is also doing the AJAX calls, I used simple jQuery method to handle better

Comment: Cool... thanks ... one more query suppose I geta response like <name>yatin<name> I need to display yatin as some string on anothet html page ... how can I do thiss...

Comment: Ideally you'd get a json with this format {"name" : "Yatin"} in javascript. All you've to do is to read this data as `var name = data["name"]`, then you can do anything with thsi data