# Loading screen example

Tags: html, splash-screen, loader

My HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\coeconsultant3\Desktop\Loadingexample\abccss.css">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {

            $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");

        })
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <div id="page1">
        <p>
            <h1>Hello World !!!
            </h1>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS for loader :**

```css
#loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('C:/Users/coeconsultant3/Desktop/Loadingexample/page-loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
}
```

I have used script which does different behaviour:

When I use `div` `id = loader`, it shows directly the hello world.

When I use `div` `class = loader`, it just shows loading gif image and does not go through the page.

I want to know the error for this program

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a fiddle.

Comment: What kinda of fiddle ??

Comment: You want the Hello World text to show up as if it is fading in?

Comment: @Yatin a fiddle from http://jsfiddle.net/ - Just like a typical webpage editor but can be saved and shared to other people. Check my answer with a fiddle. Hope it helps! =)

Comment: Can you provide a css for loader ?

Comment: @SajadLfc although quite recommended, semicolons in JavaScript is optional.

Comment: Please reply to my answer posted below. I think that mightbe your issue

Comment: Yes that was the issue @bikas now I want to extend this for request response thing ... the question I posted for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570283/html5-request-response-webservice please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works perfectly fine. And for information `$(document).ready()` is better to use.

The way you've linked your CSS, I assume you're directly opening the HTML file, i.e. by double clicking on the file (correct me if I'm wrong). If this is the case then you've to correct your jQuery linking to:

`<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I want this program to extend to webservice hit request and response... how can I do it I have posted a similar question... but no concrete answer

Comment: Drop me the URL of the question. I'll try solving that

Comment: Get http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570283/html5-request-response-webservice question I posted

Answer (score 2):

Two problems with your both scenarios :

***Problem 1 : When you apply class="loader" :***

Here the problem is that when you use **class="loader"** your **css** applies to the div. and in javascript you are using **$("#loader")** instead of **$(".loader")**

***Problem 2 : When you apply id="loader" :***

Here the problem is that you remove the class="loader" and add id="loader" so your css will not be applied to the div.

***Solution :*** 
Update your div with class as mentioned below :

```
<div id="divloader" class="loader"></div>
```

Update your javascript as mentioned below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {

        $("#divloader").fadeOut("slow");

    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**problem:** you are missing a semicolon `;` at the end of the function

change to

```
 $(window).load(function () {

            $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");

        });
```

and add this too

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#page1").fadeIn(3000)
});
```

don't forget to give `style="display:none;"` for `div page1`

Hope it helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead  of

```
$(window).load(function () {
 //your code
});
```

use

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 //your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives the `fadeIn` effect you wish to have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('body').css('display', 'none');
            $("body").fadeIn("slow");

});
```

And here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k23WQ/1/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: instead of `$('body').css('display', 'none'); $("body").fadeIn("slow");` you can simply do `$('body').hide().fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: I never thought of .hide() in order to make the codes simpler and shorter, thanks @Ashish Kumar! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dvLoading"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#dvLoading
{
   background:#000 url(images/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#dvLoading').fadeOut(2000);
});
</script>
```

Here is a [reference and demo](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/06/show-loading-image-while-page-is.html).